# Connect gcloud SQL from another project

Tags: java, google-cloud-sql

I have a database (google cloud SQL) into a gcloud project (A) and I need to read/write on it from another gcloud project (B). My problem is that the project B cannot do those actions to the database on project A. I think is a privileges problem.

I found this in the official documentation (https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-app-engine):

> 1) Grant the application access:
>
> Go to the Cloud SQL Instances page in the Google Cloud Platform. 
>   Console. Click the instance name to open its Overview page. Select
>   Access Control > Authorization. In the Authorized App Engine
>   applications section, click Add application ID and enter the
>   application ID. Click Done to exit edit mode. Click Save to update the
>   instance.
>
> 2)Update your application:
>
> Go to the Cloud SQL Instances page in the Google Cloud Platform
>   Console. Click the instance name to open its Overview page. Copy the
>   Instance connection name from the Properties. Use the following
>   connection string in your application:
>
> /cloudsql/< INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME >

The problem is that the menu is not exactly as it says.

Also, I found another short set of instructions on: gcloud console-> SQL-> "id_of_instance" -> Authorization: image of instructions.

[image]

However, it did not work.

This is my connection string:

> < property name="ae-cloudsql.cloudsql-database-url" 
>               value="jdbc:google:mysql://project:us-central1:instance/database?user=user&password=pass" />

The error I have when I try to create the connection is:

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure. The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.

My line code to create this connection is:

```
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(System.getProperty("ae-cloudsql.cloudsql-database-url"));
```

Thank you so much.

Comment: _"However, it did not work"_ : Could you add more details about errors you see? The screenshot you included is not English.  I suspect having an English image could help more people to have a look.

Comment: Sorry for the image, it is fixed. Also I add the error and my code when I create the Connection

Comment: In the "AUTHORIZATION" tab of your instance, have you tried to add the "Authorized network" "0.0.0.0" to see if that helps? Careful though, I think this makes your instance wide open to the internet... But if there's nothing special in your instance and it's just temporary, it might help debugging. If it starts working, then it might be just a matter of getting the correct network IP range from the other project and authorizing it there.

Comment: I have tried both, the 0.0.0.0 and the correct IP and It did not work. By now I have copied some data to a new database on the project A. However, I will continue trying to solve this.